# How to prove the positive definite set is open?

Tags: general-topology, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

From what I understand is that its because I can always chose some r such that the distance between $|x-x_0|\ \leq r$ is always in the set, intuitively what does this mean? because the positive semi-definite set is closed, I cant do the same thing? I am guessing its because for PD sets the boundary is not in the set? while 0 is for PSD sets. A formal proof would help.

Comment: What is a PD set or a PSD set?

Comment: positive definite and positive semi-definite

Comment: Please click on the "edit" button, and edit your post to contain the meaning of those abbreviations.

Comment: But at the same time, you also need to include the definition of the positive definite set and the positive semi-definite set, ad well as the context needed to understand the definition. It is not at all clear what you mean by that terminology.